# How to use mysql JOIN in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have same problems with my query. I havent use JOIN so far so I am pretty sure I have something wrong with it but not sure. I have tried this for hours and can not understand - It seems that code is correct but I do not get desired results.

Here are my two tables:(wrote them by hand so If there is some error dont bother)

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
msg_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
sender_id INT(11),
msg text,
conversation_id INT(11),
seen datetime,
)
CREATE TABLE conversations (
conversation_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
user1_id INT(11),
user2_id INT(11),
requested datetime,
)
```

I am working now on notification module. I want to get list of conversation_id where user with $user_id have at least one unread message so that I could notify to him that you have new messages in conversation #:

```
public function getMsgNotifications($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('conversations.conversation_id');
    $this->db->distinct('conversations.conversation_id');
    $this->db->from('conversations');
    $this->db->join('messages','conversations.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id','INNER');
    $this->db->where('conversations.user1_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->or_where('conversations.user2_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('messages.sender_id !=', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('messages.seen', '');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

However I get absolutelly random results. I have spent hours looking at values in database and trying to understand problem but the results I get has no patern.

Would appreciate if someone could point out where there are mistakes in my query.

Comment: `However I get absolutelly random results` ... what do you mean by "random?"  Are you saying that the result set changes each time you run the query or that the results are unexpected?

Comment: no need to use `'INNER'`

Comment: Sorry for misuse of word "random". I meant that I can not track down why is the result not like I though It should be

Comment: While I agree that there is no use for "INNER", that thas not cause the problem.

Comment: check sequence of where clause move this        $this->db->where('conversations.user1_id', $user_id);
            $this->db->or_where('conversations.user2_id', $user_id); to last berore get

Comment: Yeah, now I get empty result. But at least I am on track with something

Comment: sequence matters in case of or_where and or_like

Comment: I apologize in advance for this comment, downvote me if you want and report me to the authorities, get me banned from the internet or whatever but... HOW DID WE GET HERE ? Frameworks were supposed to make things easier, how is this supposed to feel easier than simply typing SQL ? In the end, using Frameworks is 10% time-saving and 90% supercomplex workarounds whenever you want to do simple things that the framework designers didn't think of.